Multiple Inheritance, use one method in child
In CPP, gTest (version does not matter too much), I have a class that I would like to monitor in my unit tests.
This class is not my code but part of the Qt Framework and named QProcess.
In my class-under-test, QProcess was called like this:
QProcess * p;
p = new QProcess;
QString cmd = "ls -lah";
p.start(cmd);

I essentially want gMock to be able to tell me once a member, e.g. QProcess::start of that class is called.
I have done it the following way: I defined an interface IQProcess and implemented it once with the mock class QProcessMock and once with something like a wrapper that just forwards the mocked methods to the original QProcessWrapper.
So my production code would now be:
IQProcess * p;
p = new QProcessWrapper();
QString cmd = "ls -lah";
p->start(cmd);

During UnitTests I exchange p with an instance of QProcessMock.
These are my classes:
interface
class IQProcess : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    virtual ~IQProcess() = default;

    virtual void start(const QString &program) = 0;
    virtual bool startDetached(const QString &program) = 0;
};

#endif // IQPROCESS_H

mock
#ifndef QPROCESSMOCK_H
#define QPROCESSMOCK_H

#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include "IQProcess.h"
#include <QObject>

class QProcessMock : public IQProcess {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, start, (const QString &program), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, startDetached, (const QString &program), (override));
};

#endif // QPROCESSMOCK_H

wrapper
#ifndef QPROCESSWRAPPER_H
#define QPROCESSWRAPPER_H

#include "IQProcess.h"
#include <QProcess>

class QProcessWrapper : public QProcess, public IQProcess {
public:
    void start(const QString &program) override {
        QProcess::start(program);
    } //<- I would like to avoid redefining those functions here

    bool startDetached(const QString &program) override {
        return QProcess::startDetached(program);
    } //<- I would like to avoid redefining those functions here
};

#endif // QPROCESSWRAPPER_H

In the wrapper, do I really have to call the underlying original function or, is there some way to tell cpp: Use the method of your parent A to implement the interface method?
Or maybe more in general: Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

I would say the whole idea of a mock is to NOT use the production implementation.  The point of having an interface (IQProcess) is so that other classes can use it (get that interface injected) so they can call the production code or a mock in test.

You have appeared to have omitted QProcess.  As this is the only part of your code that isn't glue, even a stub implmenetation may be useful.  Why does QProcess exist with method names that match IQProcess, while doesn't inherit from IQProcess?  What is the purpose of QProcessWrapper existing at all?  Without understanding that, answers to "how else can I implement this" is pointlessly constrained; there is no "why did I write it this way", so we are forced to read your mind (or take the code as specs, which reduces to "if you need code exactly like that you need that code")

I updated my description, hopefully it is more clear now
